# Creating effects over images appearing on kwicks slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kwicks

I have a problem with a kwicks slider. 
The current situation is that i have a very simple kwicks slider with 5 pictures. What i have to do is to insert another image to each one of the previous 5 when each panel of the slider expands. But i don't want the initial images disappear when the other image appears. In a way the point is to have the entrance of an image over the initial images when panels expand.

Comment: Please show us your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: current code at https://jsfiddle.net/quxfq5kk/

Comment: I'd be happy to help you out but there are still two problems with your question: (1) It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Could you draw some sketches to illustrate what you are trying to achieve? (2) Your jsFiddle doesn't work. Try Googling `jsFiddle kwicks slider` and if you find a working jsFiddle with kwicks slider, simply change it to your code and save it. Then post the jsFiddle again. If you do both things, I'll be happy to assist you.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your prompt response. Actually my slider is like the following

Comment: http://www.aoclarkejr.com/tutorial-jquery-accordion-slider/    What I want is to add a picture above of each one of the panel's picture. The entrance should be made when is panel is expanded not statically. The picture i want to add is for example a circle with some text inside in order to define the role of each one of the pictures.

Comment: So then why are you asking a question if there is a tutorial about it? You see what I mean? Please update your question to incorporate the two points I asked for, otherwise there's no point in asking a question on Stack Overflow.